# Angular2 :leave transition is not working

Tags: css, angular, animation, ionic2, angular-animations

I'm trying to hide ionic2 item after clicking a button with animation using the angular2 animation.

So after reading well the angular2 animation documentation I conclude that
`:leave = *=>void` and `:enter = void => *`. so for me the `:enter` is working well but the `:leave` isn't.

So this is my code:

```
trigger('show', [
  state('void', style({
    opacity:0
  })),
  state('*', style({
    opacity:1
  })),
  transition(':enter', animate('700ms ease-in')),
  transition(':leave', animate('700ms ease-in'))
]),
```

I can replace it by:

```
 transition('*<=>void', animate('700ms ease-in'))
```

But I used the current one for debugging.

```
<ion-row align-items-center (click)="hide()">
      <ion-col *ngIf="isShown" [@show]>
        <img class="applictant" src="assets/icon/applicants-avatar.png">
        <h2>Applicant</h2>
      </ion-col>
</ion-row> 

  hide() {
    this.isShown === false ? this.isShown = true : this.isShown = false;
}
```

So what is my issue for the `:leave` is not working and how can i solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried your animation and it's working well. Can you create a small StackBlitz example to see if you still have the problem ?

Comment: @br.julien, yea of course but I've something should be done and ill create an answer for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
trigger('show', [
            transition(':enter', [style({opacity: '0'}), animate('700ms ease-in', style({opacity: '1'}))]),
            transition(':leave', [style({opacity: '1'}), animate('700ms ease-in', style({opacity: '0'}))])
        ]),
```

Comment: One more suggestion is: maybe you have some styles for element which uses this animation, and those styles might prevent current animation styles.

Try also replace '700ms ease-in' string with number 700

Comment: I think the problem is from the nested animation